# \begin{problem} analogue to \begin{proof}

Tags: macros, environments, theorems

I recently learned about `\begin{proof} ... \end{proof}`, which is a good environment to work in. My question is whether there exists a similar environment to state a *problem*, or whether I can write some commands for something like that myself. Ideally, I would want something like this:

`\begin{problem} Prove that $2+2 = 4$. \end{\problem}`

And then it should output something like:

`\\\\\noindent\textem{Problem.} Prove that $2+2 = 4$.\\\\`

Comment: Using the `amsmath` package, you can declare `\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}`

Comment: Or `\newtheorem*{problem}{Problem}` if a number is not wanted.

Comment: are you citing the `proof` environment because you want some marker at the end, or are the suggestions regarding the various `theorem` options (with no end marker) sufficient?  (your example doesn't show an end marker, but the end marker is one of the hallmarks of `proof`.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following provides a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\begin{document}
\begin{problem}
    This is a new problem.
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To further customize the look of the `problem` environment, we can resort to the `amsthm` package and the `\newtheoremstyle` command. A MWE is given below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{problemstyle}  % <name>
        {3pt}                                               % <space above>
        {3pt}                                               % <space below>
        {\normalfont}                               % <body font>
        {}                                                  % <indent amount}
        {\bfseries\itshape}                 % <theorem head font>
        {\normalfont\bfseries:}         % <punctuation after theorem head>
        {.5em}                                          % <space after theorem head>
        {}                                                  % <theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')>
\theoremstyle{problemstyle}

\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[section] % Comment out [section] to remove section number dependence

\begin{document}
\section{Simple Problems}
\begin{problem}[Analytic]
    Prove that $2+2 = 4$.
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But also `\theoremstyle{remark}`, if it should be italicised.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Probably a second answer with your suggestion will help the OP identify what he really wants.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke -- i think you mean "should *not* be italicized".

Comment: @barbarabeeton "It" means "the word 'Problem'", as I guess from MWE.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke -- okay, i misunderstood.  but i was commenting with respect to your comment on azetina's answer -- without an alternate `\theoremstyle`, that will result in the text of the problem being italicized, which i seriously doubt is what is wanted.  (i agree with the use of the `remark` style in your answer.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton See my updated answer. I provided other tools which the OP can use other than the standard `remark` style.

Answer (score 3):

Also mine suggestion, as azetina suggested:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
Prove that $2+2 = 4$.
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]